# Is the interpretation of measurability correct for the probability measure?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $\Theta$ be a parameter space, which is a complete, separable metric space endowed with a Borel $\sigma-algebra$ $\mathcal{B}(\Theta)$.

Then for each $\theta \in \Theta$, $P_{\theta}$ is a probability measure on the measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$, such that for each $A\in\mathcal{A}$, $\theta \mapsto P_{\theta}(A)$ is $\mathcal{B}(\Theta)$ measurable.

---

Does the measurability of $P_{\theta}$ mean the following ??

We know that for fixed $\theta$, $P_{\theta}:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow [0,1]$, now if we view the probability function $P_{\theta}$ as function of $\theta$ for a fixed set $A\in \mathcal{A}$, we will have $P_{\theta}(A):\mathcal{B}(\Theta)\rightarrow [0,1]$??

Then the $\mathcal{B}(\Theta)$ measurability will mean the following ??

For each $A\in \mathcal{A}$, $P_{\theta}(A)$ is measurable in $\mathcal{B}(\Theta)$,

if for every $E\in\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ the $\left \{ \theta \in \Theta:P_{\theta}(A)\in E \right \}\subset\mathcal{B}(\Theta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition means that for each fixed $A\in \mathcal{A}$ the map

$$
f_A:\Theta \to [0,1],\quad \theta \mapsto P_\theta (A)
$$

is $\mathcal{B}(\Theta )$-measurable. Note that each $P_\theta $ is a measure, not a function, so it doesn't make sense to ask about if it is measurable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, to sum up we know that the probability measure $P_{\theta}$, is defined from a $\sigma-algebra$, in our case $\mathcal{A}$, to $[0,1]$. Then for the measurability of the map $\theta \mapsto P_{\theta}(A)$ we use the standard definition of measurable functions.  However, the form of $f_{A}$ is arbitrary or $f_{A}(\theta) = P_{\theta}(A)$ ?

Comment: yes, $f_A(\theta )=P_\theta (A)$, this is what it mean the notation $f_A:\Theta \to [0,1],\quad \theta \mapsto P_\theta (A)$. This is the usual notation to define a function, that is, we define a function setting it domain, it codomain and a mapping between both domain and codomain. The image of a point $x$ in the domain of a function $f$ is symbolically represented by $f(x)$